# Как сделать показ Preloader один раз?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Preloader при каждом обновлении страницы показывается.Как сделать так чтобы только один раз при посещении страницы показался?

```js
var hellopreloader = document.getElementById("hellopreloader_preload");

function fadeOutnojquery(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 1;
  var interhellopreloader = setInterval(function() {
    el.style.opacity = el.style.opacity - 0.05;
    if (el.style.opacity <= 0.05) {
      clearInterval(interhellopreloader);
      hellopreloader.style.display = "none";
    }
  }, 16);
}
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    fadeOutnojquery(hellopreloader);
  }, 1000);
};
```

```css
#hellopreloader>p {
  display: none;
}

#hellopreloader_preload {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f22613;
  background-size: 69px;
}

.preloader_block {
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(https://demo.mygabrielyan.ru//wp-content/themes/dvk_theme/assets/images/circles.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 30%;
}

.preloader_block a {
  position: absolute;
  top: -90%;
  left: 21%;
}
```

```html
<div id="hellopreloader">
  <div id="hellopreloader_preload">
    <div class="preloader_block">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Записывайте информацию в куки.

Comment: не подскажете как записать в куки ?

Comment: [JavaScript Cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) (я кстати думал, что это делается по другому, примерно как с LocalStorage.